# Cordova iOS sim shows blank screen

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I am using AngularJS 1.5.X and Cordova 6.1.1 to make an application.  It is compiling into the browser just fine, but will not run in the iOS simulator.  I have not tested this on an Android sim. 
[Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2UWa.png)

[iOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVSXu.png)

The output log for both show that the build was successful.  What is going on here?  I'm not really sure what to look into.